# PostgreSQL/PostGIS: Programmatically generate buffer until two rows are returned

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL 9.6 database i.e., line and building containing geometry columns. The following query returns the intersection of buffer around street and building geometry (when true in a given distance).

```
Select
building.geom as bu_geom
From
line
left join building on
/* start by 1 meter buffer*/
st_intersects(ST_Buffer(line.geom, 1), building.geom)
```

There are two building polygons on both sides of line at 11 and 15 meters respectively. I need to modify above query such that buffer should start from 1 meter and continue to increase until two rows (both buildings) and buffer distance are returned. Can somebody suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need iteration for increase buffer distance so must use plpgsql.
There are two options `Create Funtion` or `DO $$` in query editor.

Here is the second;

```
do  LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$ 

begin
 EXECUTE 'drop table if exists t';
 EXECUTE 'create temporary table t ( fid int, geom geometry)';
 FOR i in 1..15
    LOOP
    EXECUTE 'insert into t (fid,geom)  select a.objectid,a.geom
    from line y, building a 
    where st_intersects(st_buffer(y.geom,$1),a.geom) 
    and a.fid not in (select fid from t)
    and y.geom&&a.geom' using i;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

- a.fid not in (select fid from t) --> Control line
- FOR i in 1..15 iteration is here up to 15
- y.geom&&a.geom to accelerate result

At last;

```
select * from t
```

This solution is very slow, if you explain your real aim , better queries should write.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help. My aim is to calculate the sum of distance from line to the buildings on both sides. Buildings could be on the same and unequal distances as well for example building on the left side could be nearer than the building on the right side so I chose this approach to generate buffer and increment buffer until buildings on both sides of the line are selected.